# Drools knowledge in database like mySQL or mongo

Tags: java, drools

We have knowledge for Drools that could be stored in the database Is there any was i can use database tables in drools for storing knowledge at present we use spreadsheet. Please let me know if you need more info thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Look up the keyword 'from' in the user manual. http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.5.0.Final/drools-expert-docs/html/index.html

Answer (score 0):

This seems related to [Drools: storing rules in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392664/drools-storing-rules-in-database).
Please see the other post. It may answer your question. Hope this helps.